# OpenGL textures into AHardwareBuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I came across `AHardwareBuffer` in Android. I wanted to make use of AHardwareBuffer to store textures so that I can use them on different threads where I don't have an OpenGL context. Currently, I'm doing the following:

- Generate a texture and bind it to `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.
- Create `EGLClientBuffer` and `EGLImageKHR` from it. Attach the EGLImage as texture target.
- Generate an FBO and bind it to the texture using `glFramebufferTexture2D`.
- To draw the texture (say `tex`), I'm rendering it onto the `AHardwareBuffer` using shaders

However, I wanted away so that I don't need to rerender it onto hardwarebuffer but instead directly store data of the texture onto hardwarebuffer.

I was thinking of using `glCopyTexImage2d` for doing this. Is this fine and would it work?

Also (a dumb question but I cannot get over it) if I attach my `EGLImage` which is from the Hardwarebuffer to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and define the texture using glTexImage2D, would it not store the data of the texture which is a parameter of `glTexImage2D` into the hardwarebuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue using `glSubTexImage2D`.

First create a opengl texture and bind it to `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.
Then use `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` to bind texture to `EGLImageKHR` created from EGLClientBuffer. This is similar to `glTexImage2D`. Any subsequent call to `glTexImage2D` will break the relationship between the texture and EGLClientBuffer.

refer: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

However `glSubTexImage2D` preserves the relationship. Hence we can load data with this API and store it in `AHardwareBuffer`.

PS: This might me one way and if there are other ways i'll be accepting the answer.

Comment: Do you have a code sample, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create EGLClientBuffer from AHardwareBuffer
2. Create EGLImageKHR from EGLClientBuffer
3. Bind EGLImageKHR to a texture
4. Bind the texture to a fbo, then draw to it.

```
// Create AHardwareBuffer
AHardwareBuffer_Desc buffDesc;
buffDesc.width = 1920;
buffDesc.height = 1080;
...
AHardwareBuffer* hardwareBuffer;
int error = AHardwareBuffer_allocate(&buffDesc, &hardwareBuffer);
if (0 != err)//NO_ERROR
{
    LOGE("GraphicBufferEx HardwareBuffer create error. (NO_ERROR != err)");
    return;
}

// Create EGLClientBuffer
EGLClientBuffer clientBuffer = eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID(hardwareBuffer);

// Create EGLImageKHR
EGLImageKHR eglImageKHR = eglCreateImageKHR(
            mEGLDisplay, mEGLContext,
            EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID, clientBuffer, 0);

// Bind to texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId);
glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, (GLeglImageOES)eglImageKHR);

// 绑定fbo
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);

// Call OpenGL Draw
...

// Call finish to make sure the content is render to HardwareBuffer.
glFinish()
```